# Weblogic different ojdbc library on servers

Tags: weblogic, ojdbc

im running multiple servers on weblogic domain.

Is it possible to run different ojdbc drivers on servers?

adding classpath under server start configuration doesnt work, also deploying with application  and deploying on server as a library doesnt overrride default.

Thanks for help

Comment: Why doesn't changing the `Server Start` classpath work? The docs say to just include the new drivers: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13737/third_party_drivers.htm

Comment: I made this changes and restart, but no effect. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/startstop/ConfigureStartupArgumentsForManagedServers.html

Answer (score 0):

First, basic checklist...you do use NodeManager don't you (server start tab won't do anything if you don't). Also, you made sure the new driver name is configured in the JDBC datasource (I'm assuming the driver is for a datasource right?)

Deploying in the app shouldn't do anything since the datasource object is created prior to deployment.

You might want to take the old ojdbc6.jar, for JDK 6, and ojdbc5.jar, for JDK 5, out of the directories to make sure they're not seen anymore.

Also, where in the classpath did you put the new path ? When you add another path you should always put it in the beginning (after patches though)

Comment: Due to documentation i think its not posssible: "Since weblogic.jar is in the $CLASSPATH, applications can not override any WebLogic Server classes."